# generate v parameter in ethereum transaction

Tags: signature, raw-transaction

I'm trying to generate ethereum raw transactions.

this is keccak hash of my transaction:

```
f2ad2e2b6f398f76df2f5adacc84e39e926871bd2f82a3055319f8d4f4eeb8ce
```

after signing it with my private key I obtained this values:

```
r= 4041e0cf580308bcedc1f0a136029ff5200827f9dacad8c3b4884ab1350c031f
s= 0e0a5e601489fbd5a647e0423f0cf84c80b7d14cb3bf61e066184b2d94c7a267
```

now at the end I must calculate value of **v**

I found two formulas for it:

```
# CHAIN_ID=1
1) v = CHAIN_ID * 2 + 35
2) v = CHAIN_ID * 2 + 36
```

I don't know which formulas must I use.

now exactly how must I detect which formulas must I use ?

Comment: What code/library are you using to sign the transaction?

Comment: @smarx I'm using php. my library: [simplito/elliptic-php](https://github.com/simplito/elliptic-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the [library you're using](https://github.com/simplito/elliptic-php), see https://github.com/simplito/elliptic-php/blob/d6c5ecaaf434a52449f5e8faa350311c9fd1dd7a/tests/ECDSATest.php#L305:

```
$recid = $ec->getKeyRecoveryParam($msg, $signature, $key->getPublic());
```

Or perhaps `$recoverParam` is already a member of `Signature`? See https://github.com/simplito/elliptic-php/blob/master/lib/EC/Signature.php#L12.

In any case, I imagine that the recovery param is 0 or 1. You'll need to add to it to get the right `v` value for the chain you're using.

Comment: `$recoverParam` is always member of Signature and always return me `0` . now what must I add to it ?

Comment: It might help to look at the code for `ethereumjs-tx`: https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx/blob/master/index.js#L146 for where to include the chain ID in the transaction before  RLP encoding and hashing, and https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx/blob/master/index.js#L231 for what to add to the recovery bit to get the right `v` value.

Comment: value of `$recoverParam` for me always is `0` and according to [your link](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx/blob/master/index.js#L231), value of `v` always is `10` for me. but in [EIP-155](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md) says that value of `v` always must be `37` or `38`

Comment: `ethUtil.ecsign` [already adds 27](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-util/blob/master/index.js#L364) to the recovery value, so adding 10 more would give you 37 or 38.

Comment: ok. so first I must add `27` to `$recoverParam` and put it in `v` and then do this: `v += CHAIN_ID * 2 +8` that gives me `37` . so the final value of `v` is `37` :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the document ([EIP-155](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md)): v of the signature MUST be set to {0,1} + CHAIN_ID * 2 + 35 where {0,1} is the parity of the y value of the curve point for which r is the x-value in the secp256k1 signing process.
which means {0,1} value is not calculateable. you must recover the sender's address from each 2 amounts of v for each recovered address is equal to the sender's address that v is the correct one.

```
y_parity_range = [0, 1]

for y_parity in y_parity_range:
    temp_v = chainId * 2 + 35 + y_parity
    recovered_address = Account.recoverHash(
        message_hash=unsigned_hash,
        vrs=(temp_v, r, s)
    )

    if recovered_address == origin_address:
        v = temp_v
```